# How does the scanf_s function work on MinGW GCC?

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, scanf, mingw-w64

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    char str[100];
    scanf_s ("%[^\n]", str);
    printf ("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

This code can be successfully compiled without any errors or warnings by MinGW GCC 11.3.0, and the exe file runs properly without any exception. Different from the function with the same name in MSVC, function scanf_s in MinGW GCC does not require a third argument when being used to input string. How does the function scanf_s work in MinGW GCC?

Comment: I am not sure if the library that MinGW uses is ISO C compliant, but you may want to take a look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for the function `scanf_s` as specified by the ISO C standard.

Comment: What makes you think that the function does not require three arguments in your case? Did you come to this conclusion only because your code compiled without errors and warnings?

Comment: Do you get a warning if you compile with the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` command-line options?

Comment: No errors or warnings even with these options

Answer (score 0):

Both the [ISO C version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and the [Microsoft version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170) of `scanf_s` require that for every use of the `%s` conversion format specifier, an additional argument is provided which specifies the size of the buffer. The same probably also applies for the library that your version of MinGW is using.

By not providing the required number of arguments to `scanf_s`, your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The fact that your program may compile and even run properly does not change the fact that your code has undefined behavior, i.e. that anything may happen, including the possibility that it may work as intended. You cannot rely on this behavior.